# Moving div to the bottom and following when scrolling

Tags: html

Hello I was gonna use this bottom bar for my site, here is the code:

```
<div class="bottombar">Text here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottombar {
  position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have googled a lot but I can't find a way to move it to the bottom and whenever I scroll down it stays there, kinda like with position fixed. The html code is also at the top of the code, even though that might don't matter.
This was just an example but I wonder how I can fix this, because these sorts of problems happens to me a lot.

Site (not with the code I am trying to add, just to see codes etc): http://roarat.me

Comment: Hi there. So you want the bar to always be visible, and stick to the bottom of the page, scrolling **with** you? For that, you're looking for `position: fixed`. If you'd like it to initially be hidden, and stay at the bottom of the content (**not** scrolling with you), you're looking for `position: relative`.

Comment: http://devdocs.io/css/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341603/obsidian-age) and [Vivick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7316365/vivick) mentioned you can use `position: fixed;` to stick an element to the bottom of the page.

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/omalinov/pen/xLZQoL)

According to [DevDocks](http://devdocs.io/css/position) items which are positioned `fixed` are considered **absolutely positioned**, therefore, they are removed from the normal document's flow, their position is computed according to the screen viewport and they don't move when the document is scrolled.